# Is there separate intrinsic for bitset64 in Visual Studio C compiler?

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, 64-bit, intrinsics

I need to set nth bit of 64 bit integer to 1;
There is an intrinsic (documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z56sc6y4(v=vs.90).aspx) :

```
unsigned char _bittestandset64(
__int64 *a,
__int64 b
);
```

which does the job.
My question is if there is a way to just do bit set (without testing) and if there is any performance hit for using bittestandset64 ignoring return value for the purpose.
I am also interested if there is a way to do that in assembly to use in GCC (for Intel Core2 to i7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of intrinsics is to take advantage of specific processor instructions and to do so with the option to still optimize the code.  The BTS, Bit Test and Set instruction in this case.  There is no dedicated instruction for "bit set".  The code generator will pay attention to you using the result value.  And if you don't use it then it also won't generate the code to convert the carry flag to a bit value.

So a simple set, like:

```
 _bittestandset64(&bits, 1);
```

produces:

```
 000007F6ED6812CE  bts         qword ptr [rax],1
```

While using the result value, like:

```
 unsigned char value = _bittestandset64(&bits, 1);
```

produces:

```
 000007F7394E14A3  bts         qword ptr [rax],1 
 000007F7394E14A8  setb        al   
 000007F7394E14AB  mov         byte ptr [value],al
```

You can't do better than a single cpu instruction, this is already as good as it gets.

Comment: I didn't know what gets generated if I don't use the return value. This solves my problem.